# How to add something into string that read by String.xml?

Tags: android, string, android-layout

I used this:

```
String message += getResources().getString(R.string.string1) + "some more word...";
```

and I wanted to send this string via sms, but it is not working. It works fine without the string resource. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should post the relevant part of your code. How is your string declared in string.xml, how do you send it via SMS, etc..

Comment: @grrigore              in this way, I declare string :                                             
 <string name="string1">Name </string>

Answer (score 1):

@forpas answer is absolutely correct, but you can also concat string resource this way.

```
<string name="name">Name %s</string>

String nameText =  getString(R.string.name,"khemraj");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `+=` operator with a `String` the result is a concatenation of the previous value of the String with some new `String`.  
When you define a String variable like this:

```
String s;
```

the variable s is not initialized, so this:

```
s+="something";
```

is not allowed.
So instead of

```
String message += getResources().getString(R.string.string1) + "some more word...";
```

do

```
String message = getResources().getString(R.string.string1) + "some more word...";
```